# How to assign parallel tasks in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, socket.io

How do I make it so my server doesn't get stuck doing the for loop and can handle other requests? It would be nice if I could do the for loop in parallel while my server does other stuff.

```
    socket.on('drawing', function() {  
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length-1; i++)
      {
        //do stuff
      }  
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Slace's answer, you can use asynchronous recursion.

```
socket.on('drawing', function {
  var i = 0;
  (function someFunction() {
    if (i < x.length - 1) {
      i++;

      // Do stuff.

      process.nextTick(someFunction)
    } else {
      // Do something else.
    }
  }());  
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) has a bunch of helper functions like [foreach](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEach) and [whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) that do exactly what you're asking for here.

Edit:

Here's a full example:

```
async = require('async');

var i = 0

async.whilst(
    // test
    function() { return i < 5; },
    // loop
    function(callback) {
        i++;
        console.log('doing stuff.');
        process.nextTick(callback);
    },
    // done
    function (err) {
        console.log('done!');
    }
);
```

Which outputs:

```
doing stuff.
doing stuff.
doing stuff.
doing stuff.
done!
```

Edit 2: Changed named functions to comments to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `process.nextTick` to move functionality away, but it wont be truly parallel, Node.js is an event driven language so it doesn't really do threads. [Here's](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick) an overview of using `process.nextTick`.